# How to fix render problem java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Cleaner in newest version of Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, ide, android-designer

My designer doesn't show any changes or content. it says it has a render problem:

[image]

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Cleaner    at
>   libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.java:81)
>      at
>   libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:231)
>      at android.graphics.RenderNode.(RenderNode.java:228)    at
>   android.graphics.RenderNode.create(RenderNode.java:243)    at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:5063) at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:5201)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:675)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:671)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:667)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:663)    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:85)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:140)

i've tried everything, installing again, updating everything, setting to older versions, changing rendering version, etc. Everything i could find on the internet doesn't seem to work.

please help

Comment: Try to check the answer from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461792/how-to-fix-render-problem-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-sun-misc-cleaner/57467923#57467923). It looks the same.

Comment: i have exactly same problem! this link is for 7 months ago! is not there a fix till now?!

Comment: it had to do with my android sdk. i had moved it to another drive but not everything was moved well. i completely deleted android studio and the android folder and installed it again. it works now.